# Regex to allow all positive integers except 'e'

Tags: angularjs, regex

I was trying to validate an input field that can have any positive integers in angular using regex.

```
regex:"/^[0-9]*$/"
```

This works fab when my input field type is `text` but when input field type is `number` , the pattern allows to enter character `e` in the input field.

I am unable to figure out **why** the regex works with input type text and not with input type number? and **how** to fix this?

**Edit:** 
There is nothing much in code, but since it's demanded, here it goes:

```
<input type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/">
```

This allows users to enter `e` in the input field, which is not desirable. I know `e` is scientific notation and resembles a correct number, but it doesn't make sense to start a number with `e` and also if it does, then it should also be allowed when input type in the text, which is not the case.
I repeat the questions again:

1. Why the `e` is not allowed with input type text and allowed with
   input type number.
2. Regex to allow **only** positive integers ( nothing except digits, no + - e .)

Comment: uhm it does work ... `e` is just a scientific notation.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Check is angular make conversion to float for `number` filed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation -- AngularJS is presumably converting the value, because this is **valid notation**.

Comment: But what if one does't want to let users type `e` in the text box?

Comment: What browser is this in? I can't duplicate in Plunker/Chrome.

Comment: I am using Chrome. I am quite sure this happens.